# How to disable mutex if called within another function locking same mutex

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, c++17, mutex

I've got a resource class being guarded by a `std::mutex`, where any methods accessing it must be locked and only executed by a single thread. This works fine if individual methods are called separately, but now I've got a requirement for batching those methods together. In this case, the mutex needs to be locked only once and those methods must not lock that mutex again(otherwise will end up in deadlock).

---

```
class Resource {
    mutable std::mutex mtx;
    int value = 10;

    void handleOpStart() const {/* Activate batch mode */ std::cout << "HandleOp activate!"<< std::endl; }
    void handleOpEnd() const {/* Deactivate batch mode */ std::cout << "HandleOp deactivate!"<< std::endl; }
public:
    int read() const  {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
        handleOpStart(); auto result =  value + 10; handleOpEnd();
        return result;
    }
    void write(int val)  {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
        handleOpStart(); value = val; handleOpEnd();
    }

    template<typename Fn>
    void batch(Fn fn) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
        handleOpStart();
        fn();
        handleOpEnd();
    }

    void print() const {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
        std::cout << "Value: " << value << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Resource r;
    r.print();
    r.write(r.read());
    r.print();

    r.batch([&] {
        // will cause deadlock
        auto someVal = r.read();
        auto someOtherVal = 10 + someVal;
        r.write(r.read() + someOtherVal);
    });
}
```

---

Now I can't remove mutex from individual methods because they can be called separately from outside batch context. I can't keep the mutex because they can also be called inside it. If I keep a boolean variable inside class that deactivates mutex on the `batch` function call, then it also deactivates the other individual functions being called from other threads, defeating the purpose again.

One solution would be to write down a non-mutex set of all the read/write functions and only call them within batch context, not outside. But the number of such resources accessing functions is large, thus increasing maintenance and might introduce bugs.

Looking for alternatives to solve this problem.

Comment: A recursive mutex might help work around the problem, but the underlying issue is really a design problem. A class that holds data and requires locked operations should lock the mutex in every **public** member function, and those public member function should call only **private** member functions to do whatever they need to do. I was going to write an answer showing more details, but there's already an **accepted** answer, so I'm not going to waste my time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is exactly what [`std::recursive_mutex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/recursive_mutex) is for, it can be locked multiple times from the same thread. It will only fully unlock when the number of unlock calls matches the number of lock calls.

Comment: My assumption might be wrong, but I would still need to somehow conditionally use recursive_mutex for batch usage vs normal mutex for separate methods? Or does the recursive_mutex automatically detects if it's the same thread then let it pass, otherwise block?

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal A `recursive_mutex` works just like a regular one, so it will block the thread if another thread already has a lock.  It just allows one thread that has a lock to lock multiple times, but it also must be unlocked the same amount of times in said thread.

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal `std::enable_if` is your friend then?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ how would it help?

Comment: @NathanOliver undersood, it will def work.

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal As Nathan said, `recursive_mutex` can do everything the ordinary one can + support multiple locking, it is meant exactly for these cases, even the linked example shows your usage.

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal, Re, "...does the recursive_mutex automatically detects if it's the same thread...?" Yes. That is exactly what it does. The same thread can "lock" the mutex more than one time. It must then "unlock" it an equal number of times before any other thread will be allowed to lock it.